# How to add new date column while creating table from existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add `date_col` to `new_table_name`, I am trying the query below  but getting an error

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table_name AS
           SELECT A.employee AS employee_name,
           A.loc AS location,
           'America' country,
           date_col TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
           FROM existing_table_name;
```

Comment: Have you tried, creating the table then populating?

Comment: yes, that is working but I want timestamp and that I was not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` is not intended for adding new behaviors to the new table.  Changes such as adding a default value to a column should happen in a separate `ALTER` statement.  Therefore, use this approach:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table_name AS
SELECT employee,
       location,
       'America',
       date_col,
FROM existing_table_name;

ALTER TABLE new_table_name
MODIFY COLUMN date_col TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If you intended those aliases to be instructions to change the column names, then you'll need `ALTER` statements for those too:

```sql
ALTER TABLE new_table_name 
RENAME COLUMN employee TO employee_name;
```

Comment: Actually, just creating the exact table you want and then using `INSERT INTO new_table_name (...) SELECT ... FROM existing_table_name` might work better for you in this case.

Comment: yes @Tim Biegeleisen, thank you once again for your time